# Why wouldn't a WordPress site show a favicon that was sitting in the root directory?

Tags: wordpress, favicon

My wife has a WordPress site hosted on HostGator. She asked me to add an icon to the site, so I simply went to the root directory and dropped my favicon.ico file (along with other related files). I cleared my browser cache and reloaded the website, but I was still seeing the little HostGator icon.

I then went into the WordPress customization screen and set the Site Icon to my favicon file and it worked.

Does Wordpress somehow control which icon is displayed? The Site Icon is blank by default so it shouldn't have been looking for a different file.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to a caching issue (even after you cleared your cache). You should visit your site with a browser you normally don't use.

You can test your site with the [favicon checker](https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker) to better understand what is going on. Note: I'm the author of this tool.